# What is the proper way to unit test Service with NestJS/Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

Im trying to unit test a Service that uses elastic search. I want to make sure I am using the right techniques.

I am new user to many areas of this problem, so most of my attempts have been from reading other problems similar to this and trying out the ones that make sense in my use case. I believe I am missing a field within the createTestingModule. Also sometimes I see `providers: [Service]` and others `components: [Service]`.

```js
   const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PoolJobService],
    }).compile()
```

**This is the current error I have:**

```
    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PoolJobService (?). 
    Please make sure that the argument at index [0] 
    is available in the _RootTestModule context.
```

**Here is my code:**

**PoolJobService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ElasticSearchService } from '../ElasticSearch/ElasticSearchService'

@Injectable()
export class PoolJobService {
  constructor(private readonly esService: ElasticSearchService) {}

  async getPoolJobs() {
    return this.esService.getElasticSearchData('pool/job')
  }
}
```

***PoolJobService.spec.ts***

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { PoolJobService } from './PoolJobService'

describe('PoolJobService', () => {
  let poolJobService: PoolJobService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PoolJobService],
    }).compile()

    poolJobService = module.get<PoolJobService>(PoolJobService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(poolJobService).toBeDefined()
  })
```

I could also use some insight on this, but haven't been able to properly test this because of the current issue

```js
  it('should return all PoolJobs', async () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(poolJobService, 'getPoolJobs')
      .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]))

    expect(await poolJobService.getPoolJobs()).resolves.toEqual([])
  })
})
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First off, you're correct about using `providers`. `Components` is an `Angular` specific thing that does not exist in Nest. The closest thing we have are `controllers`.

What you should be doing for a unit test is testing what the return of a single function is without digging deeper into the code base itself. In the example you've provided you would want to mock out your `ElasticSearchServices` with a `jest.mock` and assert the return of the `PoolJobService` method.

Nest provides a very nice way for us to do this with `Test.createTestingModule` as you've already pointed out. Your solution would look similar to the following:

#### PoolJobService.spec.ts

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { PoolJobService } from './PoolJobService'
import { ElasticSearchService } from '../ElasticSearch/ElasticSearchService'

describe('PoolJobService', () => {
  let poolJobService: PoolJobService
  let elasticService: ElasticSearchService // this line is optional, but I find it useful when overriding mocking functionality

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        PoolJobService,
        {
          provide: ElasticSearchService,
          useValue: {
            getElasticSearchData: jest.fn()
          }
        }
      ],
    }).compile()

    poolJobService = module.get<PoolJobService>(PoolJobService)
    elasticService = module.get<ElasticSearchService>(ElasticSearchService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(poolJobService).toBeDefined()
  })
  it('should give the expected return', async () => {
    elasticService.getElasticSearchData = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({data: 'your object here'})
    const poolJobs = await poolJobService.getPoolJobs()
    expect(poolJobs).toEqual({data: 'your object here'})
  })
```

You could achieve the same functionality with a `jest.spy` instead of a `mock`, but that is up to you on how you want to implement the functionality.

As a basic rule, whatever is in your constructor, you will need to mock it, and as long as you mock it, whatever is in the mocked object's constructor can be ignored. Happy testing!

**EDIT** 6/27/2019

About why we mock `ElasticSearchService`: A unit test is designed to test a specific segment of code and not make interactions with code outside of the tested function. In this case, we are testing the function `getPoolJobs` of the `PoolJobService` class. This means that we don't really need to go all out and connect to a database or external server as this could make our tests slow/prone to breaking if the server is down/modify data we don't want to modify. Instead, we mock out the external dependencies (`ElasticSearchService`) to return a value that we can control (*in theory this will look very similar to real data, but for the context of this question I made it a string*).  Then we test that `getPoolJobs` returns the value that `ElasticSearchService`'s `getElasticSearchData` function returns, as that is the functionality of this function.

This seems rather trivial in this case and may not seem useful, but when there starts to be business logic after the external call then it becomes clear why we would want to mock. Say that we have some sort of data transformation to make the string uppercase before we return from the `getPoolJobs` method

```js
export class PoolJobService {

  constructor(private readonly elasticSearchService: ElasticSearchService) {}

  getPoolJobs(data: any): string {
    const returnData = this.elasticSearchService.getElasticSearchData(data);
    return returnData.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

From here in the test we can tell `getElasticSearchData` what to return and easily assert that `getPoolJobs` does it's necessary logic (asserting that the string really is upperCased) without worrying about the logic inside `getElasticSearchData` or about making any network calls. For a function that does nothing but return another functions output, it does *feel* a little bit like cheating on your tests, but in reality you aren't. You're following the testing patterns used by most others in the community.

When you move on to `integration` and `e2e` tests, then you'll want to have your external callouts and make sure that your search query is returning what you expect, but that is outside the scope of unit testing.

Comment: Awesome! This seems like the right solution. I need clarification though..

My ElasticSearchService also has an injected service in its constructor BUT we don't care about it because this solution has completely mocked the ElasticSearchService. Is this correct?

Also i came up with a solution like this
```
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PoolJobService, ElasticSearchService, APIService],
    }).compile()
```

before reading this solution. I theory was that the createTestingModule was doing all the mocking for us. is this wrong?

Comment: Correct, we don't care about `ElasticSearchService`'s dependencies because the Service itself is mocked. If you instead go with the proposed `providers: [PoolJobService, ElasticSearchService, APIService]` you will need to provide all dependencies of `ElasticSearchService` and `APIService` as Nest otherwise will just instantiate the default class (i.e. what is running when you run your server) and will need access to all the dependencies to correctly instantiate these classes. The `createTestingModule` does not mock anything for you, but allows you to use mocks in place of full classes.

Comment: I see! That makes sense. I have another question outside the scope of this question but regarding the test `'should give the expected return'`. Both yours and mine are trying to accomplish the same test but I cant help but feel this is not a helpful test. It seems like to me we are mocking a function and then expecting that mocked function to return the value that WE set it to. Again this is a seperate question, and lack of testing knowledge on my part, but could you explain why this is a useful/useless test?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer so it goes more in depth as to why I mock the way I showed.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the details. You've been super helpful!! @Jay McDoniel